# Change of AVPlayer current item (item url) and start playback

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, avfoundation, avplayer

I have a UITableView with a posts that contain URLs to a mp3 files. With a tap on a button in a UITableViewCell I plan to fetch a singleton instance of AVPlayer. How to assign new URL to a AVPlayer and start playback? AVPlayer's currentItem is only a { get } property.

This is what I have now.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class StreamMusicPlayer: AVPlayer {
    private override init(){
        super.init()
    }

    static func shared() -> AVPlayer{
        return AVPlayer()
    }

    func playItem(at itemURL: URL) {
        if StreamMusicPlayer.shared().isPlaying {
            StreamMusicPlayer.shared().pause()
        }

        //Change url of AVPlayerItem
        //And and assign it to shared() instance then begin playback
    }
}

extension AVPlayer {
    var isPlaying: Bool {
        return rate != 0 && error == nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you want. It's not perfect.

```
class StreamMusicPlayer: AVPlayer {
    private override init(){
        super.init()
    }

    static var shared = AVPlayer()

    static func playItem(at itemURL: URL) {
        StreamMusicPlayer.shared = AVPlayer(url: itemURL)
        StreamMusicPlayer.shared.play()
    }
}

extension AVPlayer {
    var isPlaying: Bool {
        return rate != 0 && error == nil
    }
}
```

I hade to change the static function to a normal variable. Every time you access `.shared()` it would initialize and return a new instance.

Then you can do:

```
StreamMusicPlayer.playItem(at: URL(string: "http://antoon.io/e/mp3/")!)
// Delay so you can hear it changing
StreamMusicPlayer.playItem(at: URL(string: "http://antoon.io/e/mp3/2.mp3")!)
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped.

Comment: Is it possible to add currentItem property to the StreamMusicPlayer class, to  to track 'shared' instance currently playing music track?

Comment: If you mean the URL you can add `static var currentItem: String?` and in `playItem()` add `StramMusicPlayer.currentItem = itemURL`